# PHP/MySql code not working on a big table , while works well on tables with 10-20 rows

Tags: php, mysql, css, progress-bar

I'm trying to match rows in two tables with similar table structure, and update the tables with primary key of the matching row of the other table. 
      The program works perfectly when both the table have small number of rows ( I've tried with 10 rows each)... but seems to enter an infinite loop when both tables have approx 10,000 rows each. 
  Further, what could be the reason that the progress bar does not updates when the tables are big.

```
<div id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;margin:10px"></div>
<h1>Successfully Matched Entries</h1>
<div id="prog_succcess" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px; margin:10px"></div>
<h1>Entries Not found</h1>
<div id="prog_fail" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;margin:10px"></div>
<!-- Progress information -->
<div id="information" style="width"></div>

<?php
// db connection statements here ..

$sqlA="select pk, truckno, station, weight, matchid from vendor";

$sqlB="select pk_id, truckno, station, weight, matchid  from truck";

$resultA=mysqli_query($con,$sqlA);

$resultB=mysqli_query($con,$sqlB);

$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "select * from vendor"));

while ($i<= $totalRows-1){
    $sqlA="select pk, truckno, station, weight, matchid from vendor";

    $sqlB="select pk_id, truckno, station, weight, matchid  from truck";

    $resultA=mysqli_query($con,$sqlA);

    $resultB=mysqli_query($con,$sqlB);

    $objA= mysqli_fetch_all($resultA,MYSQLI_NUM);

    $objB= mysqli_fetch_all($resultB,MYSQLI_NUM);

    if ($objA[$i][1]==  $objB[$j][1] && 
        $objA[$i][2]==      $objB[$j][2] && 
        $objA[$i][3]==      $objB[$j][3] && 
        ($objB[$j][4]==0)   )   {

            $str = $objB[$j][0];
            $str2 = $objA[$i][0];


        $updateA = "UPDATE `vendor` SET `does_match`=1, `matchid`='$str' WHERE pk = " . $str2;

            mysqli_query($con,$updateA) or die(mysqli_error($con));

            $updateB = "UPDATE `truck` SET  `matchid`='$str2' WHERE `truck`.`pk_id` = " . $str;
            mysqli_query($con,$updateB) or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
            $suc++;
            $i++; // set row-being-matched to next row
            $j=0; // reset truck's row number to 0

        }
        else 
        {
            //echo 
            //"Line ".$i. " not matched with line ".
            //$i."--".$j." | ";

            $j++; // set truck's row to next row number
            if ($j>=mysqli_num_rows($resultB)) { // check if end reached
                $fail++;           // set query failed
                $j=0;              // reset rows
                $i++;              // set table's next row


                //set line i as unmatched entry.


            }
        }
        $percent = intval($i/$totalRows * 100)."%";
        $percents= intval($suc/$totalRows * 100)."%";
        $percentf= intval($fail/$totalRows * 100)."%";   
        // print javascript progress bar ( just an html <div> with a width specified :)  
        echo '<script language="javascript">
        document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
        document.getElementById("prog_succcess").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percents.';background-color:green;\">&nbsp;</div>";
        document.getElementById("prog_fail").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percentf.';background-color:red;\">&nbsp;</div>";
        document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.\n'.$suc.' Entries Successfully Matched.\n" ;
        </script>';
    }   

    // Free result set
mysqli_free_result($resultA);
mysqli_free_result($resultB);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: What kind of indexing do you have on the tables? 10K rows is a walk in the park for MySQL.

Comment: the columns pk on vendor table, and pk_id on 'truck'  table are primary keys

Comment: But are they [indexed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html)?

Comment: no they are not. Can you please suggest some edits in the code to achieve the result I need.?

Comment: Check the link I posted. You don't change your code, you change your tables.

Comment: I have tried indexing but didn't help. Please suggest a code edit

Comment: If I read your code correctly. Assuming you have 10000 rows in vendor and truck, the total number of select queries you run will be `3 + (10,000 * 2)` with each iteration in the while loop producing 20,000 select results which comes to a total of `10,000 * 20,000`. I will also assume you have initiated `$i` to 0. This doesn't include the update queries.